# Custom UITableViewCell using storyboard and subclass

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, subclass

I have created a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and I called it `DCCustomCell`. This is the `DCCustomCell.h` file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DCCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *date;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *price;

@end
```

All the proprieties are correcty connected with elements in my `iPhone.storyboard` file.
I also selected the tableViewCell in `iPhone.storyboard` and i setted my cell's identifier to "CustomCell" and the class to `DCCustomCell`.

This is the UITableViewController's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.tableView registerClass:[DCCustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

and this is the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"CustomCell";

    DCCustomCell *cell = (DCCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    NSLog(@"%@" ,cell);

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info_button.png"];
    cell.title.text = @"Hello!";
    cell.date.text = @"21/12/2013";
    cell.price.text = @"€15.00";

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that the imageView is correctly setted, but all the labels are blank. If I change the imageView property name to, for example, eventImageView, the image will not be setted.
This is the result:

[image]

I can't figure out how I can solve this problem.

**EDIT:** if I remove

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[DCCustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

from `viewDidLoad` all seems to work. why?

Answer (score 9):

As you noticed it works when you remove

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[DCCustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

You only have to do this if you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath:` AND have not already set the custom class in the identity inspector for that cell. If you use `registerClass: forCellReuseIdentifier` the cell will be initialized with `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` instead of `initWithCoder:` thus screwing up your connections you made in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Have you bind the Controls to IBOutlet ?
You can try setting DCCustomCell to UITableviewCell's class directly in Storyboard.
And than you need to set outlets with controls in cell

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (cell == null) {
    //create and initialize cell
}
```

after

```
DCCustomCell *cell = (DCCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

You first check your outlets properly that all the labels are connected & write this also :

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *identifier = @"CustomCell";

        DCCustomCell *cell = (DCCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DCCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@" ,cell);

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info_button.png"];

        cell.title.text = @"Hello!";

        cell.date.text = @"21/12/2013";

        cell.price.text = @"€15.00";

        return cell;
    }
```